# Invariant factor form

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to write the group $\mathbb{Z}/10 \times \mathbb{Z}/12 \times  \mathbb{Z}/30$ in invariant factor form. Since the order of this group is $3600$, do I first find the elementary divisors of $3600$ and I use that info to find the invariant factors, or? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should decompose this group according to the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. Since
\begin{align}
&\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z,\\
&\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z,\\
&\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z,
\end{align}
the elementary factor system is
$$
\{2,5,3,4,2,3,5\},
$$
from which it follows that the invariant factors are
$$
\{2,2\times 3\times 5,4\times 3\times 5\}.
$$
Hence the invariant factor form of this group is
$$
\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/60\mathbb Z.
$$